# Xcode: How to download the HTML-Code of an URL via AFNetworking

Tags: html, objective-c, download, afnetworking

My goal is it to **download the COMPLETE HTML-Code of an website from an URL** but I am just getting the first lines of HTML-Code an not the whole one!
I am using following method to download HTML-Code from an URL:

```
 NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
  AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
  [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n %@", string);
  } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
  }];
  [op start];
```

Comment: Why you want to download HTML code?

Comment: I developed a HTML-WebApp and I want to get it on the iPhone so that you can use this app offline although it's content is a website. @EktaMakadiya